# react final form onBlur prevents validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

Why adding an onBlur event prevents validation, like in the below example

```
<Field name="firstName" validate={required}>
    {({ input, meta }) => (
        <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input {...input} onBlur={() => console.log('blur')} type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
        {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
        </div>
    )}
</Field>
```

If I remove onBlur event validation, it works fine.How can add onBlur event as well as show validation too?

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/qzz8wk076

Comment: why don't you use validateOnBlur if you want to trigger validation on OnBlur event?

Comment: Won't happen as the default onBlur of the form is overwritten.

Comment: I meant removing the onBlur functionality you wrote and instead, turning on validateOnBlur boolean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Final-form relies on knowing when the fields trigger the `blur` event. You'll notice if you inspect the `input` argument provided to your render function, that react-final-form does this by adding an `onBlur` handler to this `input` argument that you then typically spread as a prop to your `input` element. If you want your own custom `onBlur` behaviour as well, you must call `input.onBlur` inside your custom blur handler, like the following:

```
<Field name="firstName" validate={required}>
  {({ input, meta }) => (
    <div>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input
        {...input}
        onBlur={e => {
          console.log("blur");
          input.onBlur(e);
        }}
        type="text"
        placeholder="First Name"
      />
      {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
    </div>
  )}
</Field>;
```